# Minio data does not persist through reboot

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, minio

I deployed Minio on Kubernetes on an Ubuntu desktop. It works fine, except that whenever I reboot the machine, everything that was stored in Minio mysteriously disappears (if I create several buckets with files in them, I come back to a completely blanks slate after the reboot - the buckets, and all their files, are completely gone).

When I set up Minio, I created a persistent volume in Kubernetes which mounts to a folder (`/mnt/minio/minio` - I have a 4 TB HDD mounted at `/mnt/minio` with a folder named `minio` inside that). I noticed that this folder seems to be empty even when I store stuff in Minio, so perhaps Minio is ignoring the persistent volume and using the container storage? However, I don't know why this would be happening; I have both a PV and a PV claim, and kubectl shows that they are bound to each other.

Below are the yaml files I applied to deploy my minio installation:

```
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: minio-pv-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 100Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/minio/minio"
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: minio-pv-claim
  labels:
    app: minio-storage-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 99Gi
```

```
apiVersion: apps/v1 #  for k8s versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2  and before 1.8.0 use extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  # This name uniquely identifies the Deployment
  name: minio-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: minio
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        # Label is used as selector in the service.
        app: minio
    spec:
      # Refer to the PVC created earlier
      volumes:
      - name: storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          # Name of the PVC created earlier
          claimName: minio-pv-claim
      containers:
      - name: minio
        # Pulls the default Minio image from Docker Hub
        image: minio/minio:latest
        args:
        - server
        - /storage
        env:
        # Minio access key and secret key
        - name: MINIO_ACCESS_KEY
          value: "minio"
        - name: MINIO_SECRET_KEY
          value: "minio123"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9000
          hostPort: 9000
        # Mount the volume into the pod
        volumeMounts:
        - name: storage # must match the volume name, above
          mountPath: "/mnt/minio/minio"
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: minio-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 9000
      targetPort: 9000
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: minio
```

Comment: Also, when I run `kubectl get services` it shows that the `minio-service` service has an `EXTERNAL-IP` of `<pending>`. Not sure if that is related or if that matters...

Answer (score 0):

you need to mount container's **/storage** directory in the directory you are mounting on the container **/mnt/minio/minio/**;

```
args:

    - server
    - /mnt/minio/minio/storage
```

But consider deploying using StatefulSet, so when your pod restarts it will retain everything of the previous pod.